# c++ error: call to 'g' is ambiguous. By reference and regular function argument

Tags: c++, reference

In this code I want to call second function (with reference argument). How I can do this? This is even possible?

```
void g(int){ std::cout << 1; }
void g(int&){ std::cout << 2; }

int main() {
  int i = 42;
  g( i ); // want to output "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to have `1` when calling `g(42)` and `2` when calling `g(i)`?

Then you should change the prototype of the first function to get a `const int &`:

```
#include <iostream>

void g(const int&){ std::cout << 1; }
void g(int&){ std::cout << 2; }

int main() {
  int i = 42;
  g( i ); // want to output "2"
}
```

For `g(i)` the `int &` is a better fit than the `const int &`, so it will call the second.

Comment: In my question, I meant that I want something like `g( std::ref(i) )` to call second function.
But your answer migth actualy work too. As `g( (const int)i )` and `g( i )`. thx

Comment: @lazzlo any parameter, that is not a non-const lvalue, will call the first function, even `g(+i);` or `g((int)i);`: https://ideone.com/fxJorF

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it exactly like that. To overload functions, at least one of the arguments needs to be of a different type, or have a different number of arguments (see: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/). You could achieve something similiar, but rather unadvisable like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void g(int){ std::cout << 1; }
void g(long int&){ std::cout << 2; }

int main() {
  int i = 42;
  g(i); // outputs 1

  long int i = 42;
  g(i); // outputs 2
}
```

You can also get more information on function overloading [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr314.htm)